# ASP.NET Core MVC: $(document).ready is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a Razor view like this which is the layout of the website

```html
<link href="~/Contents/Material/css/memenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Contents/Material/js/memenu.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".memenu").memenu();
    });
</script>
<script src="~/Contents/Material/js/simpleCart.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

This is where `memenu.js` is located: "~/Contents/Material/js/memenu.js".

It looks like the URL is correct. However, the `$(document).ready()` doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the definition of `memenu`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.memenu = function (e) {
        function r() {
            $(".memenu").find("li, a").unbind();
            if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                o();
                s();
                if (n == 0) {
                    $(".memenu > li:not(.showhide)").hide(0)
                }
            } else {
                u();
                i()
            }
        }

        function i() {
            $(".memenu li").bind("mouseover", function () {
                $(this).children(".dropdown, .mepanel").stop().fadeIn(t.interval)
            }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
                $(this).children(".dropdown, .mepanel").stop().fadeOut(t.interval)
            })
        }

        function s() {
            $(".memenu > li > a").bind("click", function (e) {
                if ($(this).siblings(".dropdown, .mepanel").css("display") == "none") {
                    $(this).siblings(".dropdown, .mepanel").slideDown(t.interval);
                    $(this).siblings(".dropdown").find("ul").slideDown(t.interval);
                    n = 1
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings(".dropdown, .mepanel").slideUp(t.interval)
                }
            })
        }

        function o() {
            $(".memenu > li.showhide").show(0);
            $(".memenu > li.showhide").bind("click", function () {
                if ($(".memenu > li").is(":hidden")) {
                    $(".memenu > li").slideDown(300)
                } else {
                    $(".memenu > li:not(.showhide)").slideUp(300);
                    $(".memenu > li.showhide").show(0)
                }
            })
        }

        function u() {
            $(".memenu > li").show(0);
            $(".memenu > li.showhide").hide(0)
        }

        var t = { interval: 250 };
        var n = 0;
        $(".memenu").prepend("<li class='showhide'><span class='title'>MENU</span><span class='icon1'></span><span class='icon2'></span></li>");
        r();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            r()
        })
    }
});
```

This is the path to my script:

[image: Image showing scripts]

When I run application, the website does not display the menu. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: How do you know the path to jQuery is correct? Also, have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: i just add the picture of the path to JQuery

Comment: Are you scripts declared at the top or the bottom of the layout?

Comment: its the top of the layout

Comment: do you use any platform then i will give you more information about the project. i really struggle with this

Comment: The picture you provided is meaningless. We don't know what the doc root is. You should view source in your browser and click the jQuery link to see if it loads.

Comment: where is the code for adding jquery.min.js in the code you put above ?,could you add the following code in the view and test : <script src="@Url.Content("~/Material/js/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @NghĩaNghĩa Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your scripts at the bottom of the layout. You mentioned that they are declared at the top...this will cause problems if the document is still loading whilst the scripts are executed.

Move the following to the bottom of the layout (just before the `</body>` tag):

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Contents/Material/js/memenu.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".memenu").memenu();
        });
    </script>
    <script src="~/Contents/Material/js/simpleCart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure you have them in the correct order.